# What should I do if a JSON file begins with an array?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swifty-json

So I am trying to use Swifty-JSON to go through a JSON file. The issue I am having though is that the JSON file (from the twitter API) starts with an array, an example is below:

```
[
    {
        "created_at": "Tue Mar 31 13:47:02 +0000 2015",
        "id": 582901921171796000,
    }
]
```

Lets say I wanted to read the `created_at` part, I would do the following:

```
let urlPath = "http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json?AUTHENTICATION_INFO"
let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        var err: NSError?
        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
        if err != nil {
            // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        }

        let json = JSON(jsonResult)

        let createdAt = json[0]["created_at"].string!
        println(createdAt)

    })
    task.resume()
```

This doesn't work though, I am retired with an error message which highlights my code and in the console `(lldb)` is printed out.

Does anybody know how to do this in Swifty-JSON, it is probably quit simple but I am very unsure.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the response as an NSArray in your NSJSONSerialization:

```
var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSArray
```

Comment: Thanks so much! You've fixed two of my problems now! I really appreciate it :)